# Osmdroid 5.6, offline MBTiles

Tags: osmdroid, mbtiles

I'm trying to use MBtiles offline with osmdroid,

I took code sample from here https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/OpenStreetMapViewer/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/samplefragments/tileproviders/SampleOfflineOnly.java

But always empty map shown, is there problem with my code?

my code is:

```
public class OSMDroid extends AppCompatActivity {

private MapView mapView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_osmdroid);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);


    String name = "map.mbtiles";
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/osmdroid", name);
    if (f.exists()) {
        try {

            //ok found a file we support and have a driver for the format, for this demo, we'll just use the first one

            //create the offline tile provider, it will only do offline file archives
            //again using the first file
            OfflineTileProvider tileProvider = new OfflineTileProvider(new SimpleRegisterReceiver(this),
                    new File[]{f});

            //tell osmdroid to use that provider instead of the default rig which is (asserts, cache, files/archives, online
            mapView.setTileProvider(tileProvider);

            //this bit enables us to find out what tiles sources are available. note, that this action may take some time to run
            //and should be ran asynchronously. we've put it inline for simplicity

            String source = "";
            IArchiveFile[] archives = tileProvider.getArchives();
            if (archives.length > 0) {
                //cheating a bit here, get the first archive file and ask for the tile sources names it contains
                Set<String> tileSources = archives[0].getTileSources();
                //presumably, this would be a great place to tell your users which tiles sources are available
                if (!tileSources.isEmpty()) {
                    //ok good, we found at least one tile source, create a basic file based tile source using that name
                    //and set it. If we don't set it, osmdroid will attempt to use the default source, which is "MAPNIK",
                    //which probably won't match your offline tile source, unless it's MAPNIK
                    source = tileSources.iterator().next();
                    mapView.setTileSource(FileBasedTileSource.getSource(source));
                } else {
                    mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.DEFAULT_TILE_SOURCE);
                }

            } else {
                mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.DEFAULT_TILE_SOURCE);
            }
            mapView.setUseDataConnection(false);
            mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            IMapController mapController = mapView.getController();
            mapController.setZoom(10);
            GeoPoint startPt = new GeoPoint(61.5797,51.5997);
            mapController.setCenter(startPt);
            mapView.invalidate();
            return;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
}
```

MBTilesFileArchive getTileSources always returns empty string, here is implementation:

```
public Set<String> getTileSources(){
    //the MBTiles spec doesn't store source information in it, so we can't return anything
    return Collections.EMPTY_SET;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make a offline map you should add tiles first. You can use Maperitive app to make your map tiles(zip is easier to manage than sql). Name the zip MapquestOSM. After you have done it create a folder "osmdroid" in phones memory(Directly into the internal memory or sd card) and add your map tiles in it.

Parameters of the XYTileSource changes related to the map tiles you have created. This code handles everything about map tiles itself. I hope it helps you

```
mapView.setUseDataConnection(false);
mapView.setTileSource(new XYTileSource("MapquestOSM", 2, 15, 256, ".png", new String[]{}));
```